# How to implement conversion only between "same" types

Tags: c++, templates

I am trying to implement a generic "Unit" type in C++ to represent different physical units like voltage, current, power, etc.  In addition, the "values" of these units are represented as fractions (as opposed to floating point).

I was able to create a generic (i.e., templated) fraction type as such:

```
template <typename REP>
class FractionalValue
{
public:
    using Value = REP;
    using Rep = REP;

public:
    constexpr FractionalValue() : n_(0), d_(1) {}
    explicit constexpr FractionalValue(Value numerator, Value denominator = 1) : n_(numerator), d_(denominator) {}

    constexpr double toDouble() const
    {
        return static_cast<double>(n_) / static_cast<double>(d_);
    }
    
    constexpr Value value() const
    {
        return n_ / d_;
    }
    
    constexpr FractionalValue& simplify()
    {
        auto gcd = std::gcd(n_, d_);
        n_ /= gcd;
        d_ /= gcd;
        return *this;
    }
    
    constexpr num() const { return n_; }
    constexpr den() const { return d_; }
    
private:
    Value n_;
    Value d_;
};
```

From this, I made the following statement

> "A 'unit' is a fractional value with additional 'prefix' information"

For example, a Voltage may be represented in volts, millivolts, microvolts, etc. but all three may be converted between each other.  1/2 volts = 500/1 millivolts = 500000/1 microvolts.

To implement this behavior, I came up with the following generic Unit class:

```
template <typename T, typename REP, typename RATIO = std::ratio<1>>
class Unit : public FractionalValue<REP>
{
public:
    using Ratio = RATIO;
    
public:
    using FractionalValue<REP>::FractionalValue;
    
    template <typename OTHER>
    constexpr operator OTHER() const
    {
        using NewRatio = std::ratio_divide<Ratio, typename OTHER::Ratio>;
        return OTHER(this->numerator() * NewRatio::num, this->denominator() * NewRatio::den);
    }
};
```

Which I then use as such:

```
template <typename RATIO = std::ratio<1>>
class Voltage: public Unit<Voltage<RATIO>, long long, RATIO>
{
public:
    using Unit<Voltage<RATIO>, long long, RATIO>::Unit;
};

using Volts = Voltage<>;
using Millivolts = Voltage<std::milli>;
using Microvolts = Voltage<std::micro>;
```

This all sort of works except for a few problems that I need help solving.

The conversion operator in `Unit` should only allow conversions between the same "type" of units.  For example `Millivolts` can be converted to `Volts` but `Volts` cannot be converted to `Amps`.  However, as I have written it, my conversion operator converts between all "types" of `Unit`s.

I don't know how to correctly implement the mathematical operators in a generic way while still preserving type information.

As an additional question, I am wondering if `Unit` should really be represented as "is a" `FractionalValue` (use inheritance) or should it be implemented as "contains a" (use composition) a `FractionalValue` (which is its value)?  The inheritance becomes a problem, for instance, if you call the `simplified()` method which returns a `FractionalValue` and NOT the actual `Unit`.

Comment: You may wish to see this library: https://github.com/joboccara/NamedType sine simply you trying do strong typing on some arithmetic types.

Comment: *I am trying to implement a generic "Unit" type in C++* It's **a lot** more work than you probably want to have. Ask me how I know. There are libraries that do that fo you such as `boost::units`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your `T` should be a tag and not the derived class of CRTP.

so

```
template <typename Tag, typename REP, typename RATIO = std::ratio<1>>
class Unit : public FractionalValue<REP>
{
public:
    using Ratio = RATIO;
    
public:
    using FractionalValue<REP>::FractionalValue;
    
    template <typename Rep2, typename Ratio2> // Same Tag, different Rep|Ratio
    constexpr operator Unit<Tag, Rep2, Ratio2>() const
    {
        using NewRatio = std::ratio_divide<Ratio, Ratio2>;
        return Unit<Tag, Rep2, Ratio2>(this->num() * NewRatio::num,
                                       this->den() * NewRatio::den);
    }
};

// The tags
struct Voltage;
struct DistanceTag;

// Voltage units:
using Volts = Unit<Voltage, long long, std::ratio<1>>;
using Millivolts = Unit<Voltage, long long, std::milli>;
using Microvolts = Unit<Voltage, long long, std::micro>;

// Distance units
using Meter = Unit<DistanceTag, long long, std::ratio<1>>;
using MilliMeter = Unit<DistanceTag, long long, std::milli>;

static_assert(std::is_convertible_v<Volts, Millivolts>); // Same Tag
static_assert(!std::is_convertible_v<Volts, Meter>); // Not same tag
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/EraWv3P6f).

For "mixed" units (as acceleration meter/second²), you might use some kind of `tag_ratio<std::tuple<distanceTag/*numerators*/>, std::tuple<TimeTag, TimeTag>>` as tag. It would then need some meta-prog to go further.

Comment: This is very helpful, thank you!  Would you be able to provide an example of implementing operator+ between units (perhaps of different ratios)?

Comment: [`operator+` Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/9xdPxo3Px) (pretty sure I made mistake with conversion/computation though ;-) (and some part of the code should be in `operator+` of `FractionValue`) ).

Comment: @PatrickWright `operator+` is easy. Try `operator*`. (Or maybe don't, this particular rabbit hole is *deep*).